# Asus x201e won't boot to any USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, laptop

I am trying to install Xubuntu / Ubuntu on my Asus X201E laptop, but I don't even get to the install menu, because the live usb (which I've tried making in LiLi, UNetbootin) doesn't do anything. I don't have any other OS installed and the USB is listed asi Boot Option #1.

AFAIK, the laptop only support EFI.

Comment: This is a setting in your bios to boot the usb. Ubuntu works with uefi enabled.

Comment: I've tried every possible bios setting, with 'Secured Boot Control' enabled/disabled, 'Fast Boot' enabled/disabled, 'Launch CSM' enabled/disabled and yet none of them worked.

Comment: The thing is, that it won't even start the installation, it just jumps right to bios and even if I override, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it jumped in the bios.

Comment: Does the usb boot on other machines ?

Comment: It works on my desktop.
Because I don't have anything else installed (but I had win8).

Comment: Even though I explicitly choose the usb option?

Comment: Sure, it wasn't mean as an offense. I am actually quite desperate right now. Thanks for you effort.

Comment: Also forget Lili, Unetbootin, etc. They may not be creating the usb correctly and they are not needed. On your desktop, take the 64-bit iso, confirm the checksum just in case, and `sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdb` (use sudo blkid to get the sdX letter you need and make sure you don't make a typo) Then try again

Comment: You do suppose that I am using Linux distro on my desktop, but I am using Win on it.

Comment: If you want to try the dd option, you should be able to boot the live version from you desktop and do it from there. But it may be tricky if you're not very familiar with Linux yet. Also, there used to be RawWrite for Win, but I think that's gone. Try to find a new but similar burning tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps it's worth trying another boot tool -- Rufus, pay attention to when creating USB stick,
the target system should be EFI or UEFI
and some reference info:
Even page is for win10, Ubuntu is almost same.
Click [here](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/partition-scheme-and-target-system-type-rufus-window-10-0001.html)

and also pay attention to the BIOS setting as @user280493 pointed out, the first boot option should be "USB disk EFI usbDiskName", because some BIOS distinguish "USB disk EFI usbDiskName" and "USB disk usbDiskName"

Comment: oops, this is a post long long time ago..... :)

Answer (score 0):

Power the laptop on with USB stick connected already. Some BIOSes don't recognize some USB drives that are connected after power on. And by the way: remember to have Ubuntu USB stick formatted as FAT32 file system, not NTFS. NTFS USB stick will boot, but will also fail to continue shortly after that.

Comment: The stick is already there when I boot it up and it is formated as FAT32.